# Terraform Apply throwing error related to access policy with Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a SQB DB. I would like to store the SQL Admin Password inside my Key Vault. I would like to use RBAC for providing access to my TF SP to the KV. But TF is complaining about access policy in the error message.
If i am assigning the role "Key Vault Secrets User", "Key Vault Administrator" and "Key Vault Secrets Officer" then why is TF complaining about secret set permission

I am not using KV access policy here.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "my-kv" {
  name                = "testhalvault"
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}


locals {
  role_name = [
  "Key Vault Secrets User",
  "Key Vault Secrets Officer",
  "Key Vault Administrator"
  ]
}
```

## Storing SQL PWD in the vault

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "app-pwd" {
  name         = "sql-pass"
  value        = azurerm_mssql_server.primary.administrator_login_password
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.my-kv.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.kv-iam 
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "kv-iam" {
  for_each           = toset(local.role_name)
  scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.my-kv.id
  role_definition_name = each.value 
  principal_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}



 Error: keyvault.BaseClient#SetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=290caxx-d706-xxxx-b525-cxxxxxxx3694;oid=a6552322-xxxx-4df6-a7e4-e2eb228bc3b3;numgroups=2;iss=https://sts.windows.net/15954d5b-40c8-4c1b-adca-395b42300a8c/' does not have secrets set permission on key vault 'testhalvault;location=CanadaCentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByPolicy"}
│ 
│   with azurerm_key_vault_secret.app-pwd,
│   on resources.tf line 47, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "app-pwd":
│   47: resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "app-pwd" {
│ 
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform apply (exit 1)
```

Comment: has the KeyVault `enable_rbac_authorization` set? also, maybe the role assignment takes a  bit of time to take effect? does it work when you retry after a few minutes?

Comment: The key vault isn't deployed using terraform. I am using a data block for the key vault. So what are my options here then

Comment: Well, however you deploy the key vault you need to make sure it is enabled for RBAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error:

> SetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original
> Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403
> Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application
> 'appid=290caxx-d706-xxxx-b525-cxxxxxxx3694;oid=a6552322-xxxx-xxxx-a7e4-e2eb228bc3b3;numgroups=2;iss=https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxx-40c8-4c1b-xxxx-395b42300a8c/' does not have secrets set permission on key vault
> 'testhalvault;location=CanadaCentral'. For help resolving this issue,
> please see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287%22)
> InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByPolicy"}

This error clearly mentions user , group or app should have the access policy  to have permissions to set secrets i.e.; create keyvault secret .As user or the group , in this case have `Key vault Administrator`, please check if the **application** has the permissions to access the resource-Key-Vault which is secured by Azure AD tenant.

Please set the access policy of secrets and other required something like this [***Assign an Azure Key Vault access policy (CLI) | Microsoft Docs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) :

[image]

- select the application:

[image]

or

you can set access policy with required permissions [through terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy)  something like below

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_application_access" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id # or try with client_id 

  key_permissions = [
    "get", "list", "update", "create", "import", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore",
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "get", "list", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore", "set", 
                              //set is  important as we are creating secret
  ]

 certificate_permissions = [
    "get", "list", "update", "create", "import", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore"
  ]
}
```

**References:**

1. [Terraform azure keyVault SetSecret - Forbidden Access denied -Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436836/my-terraform-service-principal-gets-a-403-access-error-on-key-vault-even-though?rq=1)
2. [Key Vault access issue from TFE(github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Terraform/terraform-azurerm-hashicorp-vault/issues/10)