# Keep getting 403 when trying to create secret in Azure Key Vault - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

Below is current Terraform file, the goal here is to create a `Key Vault` service, create the `Access Policy` which should grant the recently created `Service Principal` access to it eg `Get, set, List, Delete` permissions.

Yet when I run the following `Terraform` file, it throws, I've removed appid and oid from the below error

> keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request:
> StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or
> application
> 'appid=;oid=;numgroups=4;iss=https://sts.windows.net/acfbd79b-1411-47c0-8101-2673e2fc0893/'
> does not have secrets get permission on key vault
> 'applicationName-keyvault-ae-dev;location=australiaeast'. For help
> resolving this issue, please see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287"
> InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}

Terraform File:

```
`Variables Remove`

output "connection_string" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_secret.key_vault_secret.value
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "keyvault_rg" {
  name     = lower("${var.application_name}-keyvault-${var.location_short}-${var.environment}-rg")
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.keyvault_rg ]
  name                = lower("${var.application_name}-keyvault-${var.location_short}-${var.environment}")
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.keyvault_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.keyvault_rg.location
  tenant_id           = var.tenant_Id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  sku_name            = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = var.tenant_Id
    object_id = var.object_Id // Passed in via variable, this matches the SP in AAD
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_sp_access" {
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.key_vault ]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = var.tenant_Id
  object_id    = var.object_Id
  
  secret_permissions = ["Set", "Get", "List", "Delete",]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "key_vault_secret" {
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.key_vault, azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_sp_access ]
  name         = lower("${var.application_name}-${var.environment}-connection-string")
  value        = "connection_string"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}
```

I can confirm the `Key Vault` is created successfully, I just cant seem to get access to create a new secret.  I have reviewed this [403 Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436836/my-terraform-service-principal-gets-a-403-access-error-on-key-vault-even-though) and made the relevant changes to my file but I'm still unable to get this to work.

I've made sure the `Service Principal` has the `Contributor` role, and checked the `Key Vault` Access Configuration is set to Azure role-based access control

Comment: Still happening unfortunately

Comment: Ok, will give it 10 mins and check again, is it worth me destroy the environment and spinning it up again?

Comment: Could you include snip of Key Vault Access Configuration by editing your question?

Comment: What configuration are you referring to?

Comment: I meant your key vault Access configuration like [this](https://i.imgur.com/YEdQ8Rk.png)

Comment: Usually the error you are facing will occur if the key vault is configured with **vault access policy** but u missed adding your service principal to vault access policy permissions. Refer this [thread with similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421094/azure-keyvault-access-from-azure-devops-release-pipeline-with-no-secrets-list-pe/76423234#76423234) that I recently answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254516/discussion-between-sridevi-and-code-ratchet).

Comment: I've just destroyed the service principle and recreated via the CLI, assigned the contributor and Key Vault Admin role, in process of deploying the environment.   The Access Configuration is set to Azure role-based access control

Comment: still getting same problem even after recreating the service principal and assigned Key Vault Administrator.  I've checked inside the Key Vault - Check Access and can confirm the service principal does have the correct role.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep getting 403 when trying to create secret in Azure Key Vault - Terraform.

To resolve the issue, enable **RBAC** in the `Terraform Key Vault` block and assign the required permissions to the service principal to access the `Key Vault` secrets.

Ex:  `Keyvault Administrator`.

I have created `Key Vault` with secrets and successfully and retrieved **keys** with **service principal** authorization.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id                   = "4e23d809-ad57-xxxxxxxx-0403493fdf53"
  client_secret               = "iPr8Q~xxxxxxxxx~vyCQmkvmIT~3P.8~rcZC"
  tenant_id                   = "650cf1f2-b0e9-xxxxxxxx-627017451367"
  subscription_id             = "7195d375-7af2-xxxx-xxxxx-12xxxac05818"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "keyvaultrg" {
  name     = "keyvault-resource-group"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  depends_on                 = [ azurerm_resource_group.keyvaultrg ]
  name                       = "thhejademotest"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.keyvaultrg.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.keyvaultrg.location
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  enable_rbac_authorization  = true
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "key_vault_secret" {
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.key_vault]
  name         = "sampleScret"
  value        = "connection_string"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

output "connection_string" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_secret.key_vault_secret.value
  sensitive = true
}
```

**Key vault secret**

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

I'm able to retrieve the **Azure Secret Keys** with the `Service Principal` authorization.

[image]

Reference: [`enable_rbac_authorization`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault#enable_rbac_authorization) in Terraform.